# What package management tool can be used across OpenSuse and CentOS?

Tags: centos, yum, opensuse, zypper

I have created a project in OpenSuse and I'm trying to deploy it in CentOs using a makefile. In the dev environment, I used zypper to install all the packages and its dependencies. However, Centos uses a different high level package manager like Yum for package management. Is there a package manager that is common for both the distributions?

Comment: Is this a public or private project?

Comment: RPM, but really this is a major reason why tools like Puppet, Chef, Ansible, etc. exist.

Comment: Thank you. I'm using RPM and it worked.